# How to preserve the content of a HashMap before clearing it in Dart/Flutter

Tags: flutter, list, dart, hashmap

I am trying to create an order history screen for a list of orders for instruments. The data structures used are:

- `<Map<String, dynamic>> instrument` : map object for an instrument
- `List<Map<String, dynamic>> instruments` : list of instruments
- `List<Map<String, dynamic>> cartList` : list of instruments added to cart
- `Map<Map<String, dynamic>, int> cartMap` : maps each instrument in a cart to the number of units of that instrument chosen by the user
- `List<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> ordersList` : list of orders
- `Map<List<Map<String, dynamic>>, DateTime> ordersDate` : maps each order to a DateTime
- `List<Map<Map<String, dynamic>, int>> ordersMap` : maps each instrument of a particular order to the number of units of that instrument ordered by the user in that particular order

I have a *make_card_payment_screen.dart*, which has a pay now button. When it is pressed, the onPressed function gets called as follows:

```
ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    ordersList.add(cartList.toList());

                    ordersDate.addAll({cartList.toList(): DateTime.now()});
                    ordersMap.add(cartMap);

                    cartList.clear();
                    cartMap.clear();
                    Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/orders-history");
                  },
```

I am displaying the order history in the *order_history_screen* as follows:

```
SizedBox(
            width: screenWidth * 0.95,
            height: screenHeight * 0.8,
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: ordersList.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return SizedBox(
                        width: screenWidth * 0.95,
                        height: screenHeight * 0.10 * ordersList[index].length,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            Text("${ordersDate[ordersList[index]]}"),
                            Expanded(
                              child: ListView.builder(
                                  itemCount: ordersList[index].length,
                                  itemBuilder:
                                      (BuildContext context, int index2) {
                                    return ListTile(
                                      leading: Image(
                                          image: NetworkImage(ordersList[index]
                                              [index2]["img-url"])),
                                      title: Text(
                                          ordersList[index][index2]["name"]),
                                      subtitle: Text(
                                          "${ordersMap[index][ordersList[index][index2]].toString()} units"),
                                      trailing: Text(
                                          "₹${ordersList[index][index2]["price"].toString()}"),
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

**Issue faced**: The orders history page loads with **null** for the `ordersDate[ordersList[index]]` and `ordersMap[index][ordersList[index][index2]].toString()`. I understand that the lines

```
ordersDate.addAll({cartList.toList(): DateTime.now()});
ordersMap.add(cartMap);
```

are creating the issue here since I am unable to preserve the `cartList` and `cartMap` data in `ordersDate` and `ordersMap` after `cartList.clear()` and `cartMap.clear()` is called.

**My Question**: How do I preserve the values of `cartList` and `cartMap` in `ordersDate` and `ordersMap`?

**Screenshot for reference**:

[image]

Comment: Why are you clearing `cartMap`?  Why don't you assign it a new, empty `Map` instead?  Or, if you must make a copy, then make a copy: `ordersMap.add(Map.of(cartMap));`

Comment: @jamesdlin If I don't clear `cartMap` then on ordering a different number of units of a previously ordered instrument updates the units ordered of that instrument of the original order. e.g. if I had ordered 3 units of Guitar A in Order 1, and 2 units of Guitar A in Order 2, by not clearing `cartMap` I would be seeing 2 units of Guitar A ordered for both Order 1 and Order 2.

`ordersMap.add(Map.of(cartMap));` solves my issue, thanks.

Comment: @jamesdlin however, `ordersDate.addAll({(cartList): DateTime.now()});` still seems to have an issue, since when I try to display `ordersDate[ordersList[index]]` it returns **null**. It seems that `ordersDate.addAll({(cartList): DateTime.now()});` isn't creating a key-value pair entry in `ordersDate`. Do you know the solution for this? I have tried `ordersDate.addAll({(cartList.toList()): DateTime.now()});` but it leads to the same **null** value.

Comment: `Map<List, ...>` usually will not work because a `List` normally compares equal to another `List` only if it's the exact same object.  You don't show how you construct `ordersDate`, but you probably should use the `HashMap` (or `LinkedHashMap`) default constructor with `equals` and `hashCode` callbacks.

Comment: @jamesdlin I declared `ordersDate` as `Map<List<Map<String, dynamic>>, DateTime> ordersDate = HashMap();`

I am trying to add a key of `List<Map<String, dynamic>>` to `ordersDate` and assign it a value of current DateTime `DateTime.now()` but it seems that this key-value pair is not getting added to `ordersDate`.

Answer (score 0):

You have two cases here:

1. To add cartList elements as key and timestamp as value, you need to use .map method. Or even better to use for loop or forEach (it has much better performance).
2. To add cartMap elements to ordersMap you need to use:

   ```
   ordersMap.addAll(cartMap);
   ```

Comment: As for 2, `ordersMap.add(Map.of(cartMap));` suggested by @jamesdlin solved my issue. `ordersMap.add(cartMap);` was in my original code which was returning **null** because cartMap was being cleared later on.

As for 1, I am already using: `ordersDate.addAll({(cartList): DateTime.now()});` I will need to add one order entry at a time to ordersDate map when the payment button is pressed for a particular order. However, I am getting **null** when I try to display `ordersDate[ordersList[index]]` in the ListView item.

Comment: Sorry, I mean addAll. This will add key:value pairs from cartMap to ordersMap. If a key already exists, its value will be overwritten.